# What exactly did Yaakov learn at Yeshivat Shem v'Ever?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, midrash, pentateuch-chumash

The Midrash (Bereshit Rabba 84:8) says

> ר' נחמיה אמר שכל הלכות שמסרו שם ועבר ליעקב מסרן לו

All the laws that Yaakov learned by Shem and Ever, he taught to Yosef (his son).

What exactly did Yaakov learn? And why did he teach it only to Yosef?

Comment: See emes lyaakov parshas vayeitzei

Comment: @Nafkamina There is significantly more than one sefer with that name (hebrewbooks.org lists over 10). Which one are you thinking of (who is the author)?

Comment: Eglah arufah........

Comment: From r yaakov kaminetxky